# insert method of the simple prefix tree

Tags: python, methods, tree

I am asked to implement the insert method of the simple prefix tree which is defined as below:

```
 def insert(self, value: Any, weight: float, prefix: list) -> None:
        """Insert the given value into this autocompleter.
        The value is inserted with the given weight, and is associated with
        the prefix sequence prefix.
        If the value has already been inserted into this autocompleter,   
        then the given weight should be added to the existing weight of this value."""

        if self.root == value:
            self.weight += weight
        elif self.root == prefix:
            new_tree = SimplePrefixTree()
            new_tree.root = value
            new_tree.weight = weight
            new_tree.subtrees = []
            self.subtrees.append(new_tree)
        else:
```

The insert method, as described, should function in this way: if we are to insert the word 'pig' into the tree and there is no leaf that stores 'pig', then tree.insert('pig', 4.0, ['p', 'i', 'g']) should give us a new prefix tree, which starts from the root [] -> ['p'] -> ['p', 'i'] -> ['p', 'i', 'g'] -> 'pig'. The instance attributes of the SimplePrefixTree are self.root (returns the value stored), self.weight (returns weight in float), self.subtrees (returns the subtrees of the node as a list of SimplePrefixTree), and there are other methods called is_empty() (checking if this tree is empty, namely self.root = [], self.weight = 0.0, self.subtrees = []), is_leaf() (checking if this tree is a leaf, namely self.subtrees = [] and self.weight > 0).

This method is said that it can be implemented by recursion and I have done the base cases, yet I have no clue of doing it. Any help please?
I want to see detailed explanations and sample code with which I can simulate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, before you can implement this you need a tree to begin with.
Using [littletree](https://pypi.org/project/littletree/) (of which I'm the author), we can start by creating a tree node.

Each tree node will need to store:

- A letter
- weight of letter
- Sum of weight of leave nodes

```py
import littletree


class AutoCompleter(littletree.BaseNode):
    def __init__(self, letter=""):
        super().__init__(identifier=letter)
        self.weight = 0  # weight of leave nodes
        self.total_weight = None  # sum of weight for all leaves
```

Words need to be inserted or reconstructed. We'll add a`$` to mark where words end.

```py
    def insert_word(self, word, weight=1):
        """Adds a word to tree."""
        prefix = list(word)
        prefix.append('$')  # Add a terminal to prefix

        # Retrieve or create recursively
        word_node = self.path.create(prefix)  
        word_node.weight += weight
        return word_node

    def retrieve_word(self):
        """Get full word."""
        return "".join(segment.identifier for segment in self.path)
```

Now that we can store and retrieve words, we can make predictions:

```py
    def predict(self, partial=""):
        """Now we can make predictions"""
        prefix = list(partial)
        prefix_node = self.path.get(prefix)
        if prefix_node is not None:
            for leaf_node in prefix_node.iter_leaves():
                yield leaf_node.retrieve_word()
```

If we want our predictions to become better, we should calculate and order by total_weight.

```
    def optimize(self):
        """Sort nodes by weights."""

        # Calculate total_weights
        for node in self.iter_tree(order="post"):
            if node.is_leaf:
                node.total_weight = node.weight
            else:
                node.total_weight = sum(c.total_weight for c in node.children)

        # Sort from high total_weight to low
        self.sort_children(key=operator.attrgetter("total_weight"), recursive=True, reverse=True)
```

Finally, we can use it as follows:

```py
autocompleter = AutoCompleter()
for word in ["pig", "pork", "pigeon", "pig", "pheasant", "pinfish", "pink salmon"]:
    autocompleter.insert_word(word)
    
autocompleter.optimize()
for prediction in autocompleter.predict("pi"):
    print(prediction)
```

Our top predictions for "pi" are:

```
pig$
pigeon$
pinfish$
pink salmon$
```

Various parts of this can be tweaked depending on what you want to achieve.

Internally, the constructed tree looks something like this:

```
└─ p (7)
   ├─ i (5)
   │  ├─ g (3)
   │  │  ├─ $ (2)
   │  │  └─ e (1)
   │  │     └─ o (1)
   │  │        └─ n (1)
   │  │           └─ $ (1)
...
```

Comment: I appreciate your hard work and enthusiasm but the tree I use is simple prefix tree, rather than the littletree you wrote.

Comment: You can construct the tree in different ways, but I think the principles are the same. In SimplePrefixTree "weight" is the same" as mine. You call "identifier" a "root" instead (maybe a bit confusing), you call children subtrees (that's okay), but you implement them as a list instead of a dict (I think making it a list could make things harder).